# Images in mail can't open image

Tags: php, image, email, encoding

I've read several topic on images and mailing, but I simple can't figure this one out.

I'm sending mail with PHP to a user with an image, it delivers the mail, shows that there is a images, but that the images is broken.

Could someone look into my composed mail as it is received for any errors?

Before loading in this images, I checked its type by `getimagesize` and it says `img/png`

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

```
Subject: Screenshot compare of project: xxx
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="multipart_related_boundary"
To: xxx@gmail.com
From: xxx@gmail.com
Subject: Screenshot compare of project: xxx
X-Mailer: PHP/5.4.20

This is a multi-part message in MIME format. 

--multipart_related_boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit 

<html> 
<head> 
<title>Screenshot compare of project: static</title> 
</head> 
<body>
<p>We have found: 1 differances</p>
<p>chrometestBodyText.jpg</p>
<img alt="diffchrometestBodyText" src="cid:multipart_related_boundarydiffchrometestBodyText" />
</body>
</html>

--multipart_related_boundary
Content-ID: <multipart_related_boundarydiffchrometestBodyText>
Content-Type: image/png; 
 name=diffchrometestBodyText.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64
```

Comment: It looks like your embedded Base64 encoded image hasn't been encoded or embedded properly. Look to the code that generates the mail.

Comment: Thanks, couldnt detect wat was going wrong so I decided to use a library

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use PHPMailer library https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer